# How to sort an array of UNNotificationRequests by nextTriggerDate

Tags: ios, sorting, nspredicate, unnotificationrequest, unnotificationtrigger

I have an array of `UNNotificationRequest`. I want to sort them by `nextTriggerDate`.

As far as I understand it, I would sort the array using `array.sorted(by:predicate)`

`let sortedNotifications = notificationRequests.sorted(by: 
{ $0.trigger.nextTriggerDate?.compare($1.trigger.nextTriggerDate!) == .orderedAscending })`

However, the problem is `.trigger` doesn't have a `nextTriggerDate` property.

In order to obtain `nextTriggerDate`, I have to extract the trigger and cast it into `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger`. Which as far as I know, can't be done in a predicate.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create `Tuple` With UNNotificationRequest and nextTriggerDate `(UNNotificationRequest,nextTriggerDate)`

```
// get request with date Tuple -->  example : (value0,value1)

let requestWithDateTuple =  notificationRequests.map({ (req) -> (UNNotificationRequest,Date?)? in
                    guard let trigger = req.trigger as? UNCalendarNotificationTrigger else {
                        return nil
                    }
                    return (req,trigger.nextTriggerDate())
                }).compactMap({$0})

                // you will get Tuple (request,Date) ,sort them by date  
               let sortedTuple = requestWithDateTuple.sorted(by: { $0.1?.compare($1.1!) == .orderedAscending })

// sorted request only 
let requestSorted =  sortedTuple.map({$0.0})
```